# Coherency matrix of partially polarized light doesn't contain all information on polarization state?

Tags: polarization, statistics, coherence

The electric field of quasi-monochromatic, partially polarized light can be expressed by the following random process (Goodman, Statistical optics)
$$\bar{E}(t,\bar{x})=u_{x}(t,\bar{x})\bar{e}_{x}+u_{y}(t,\bar{y})\bar{e}_{y}$$
$$u_{x}(t,\bar{x})=\Psi_{x} e^{i(\bar{k}\cdot\bar{x}-\omega t)}$$
$$u_{y}(t,\bar{x})=\Psi_{y} e^{i(\bar{k}\cdot\bar{x}-\omega t)}$$
where $\Psi_{x}$ and $\Psi_{y}$ are radom phasor sums (which are circular complex Gaussian random variables). The joint statistics of $u_{x}=a+bi$ and $u_{y}=c+di$ describe the polarization state. Knowing that $E(u_{x})=E(u_{y})=0$, the covariance matrix of these two complex is given by
$$C=\begin{bmatrix}
E(aa)&E(ac)&E(ab)&E(ad)\\
E(ca)&E(cc)&E(cb)&E(cd)\\
E(ba)&E(bc)&E(bb)&E(bd)\\
E(da)&E(dc)&E(db)&E(dd)
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
E(aa)&E(ac)&0&E(ad)\\
E(ac)&E(cc)&E(bc)&0\\
0&E(bc)&E(aa)&E(bd)\\
E(ad)&0&E(bd)&E(cc)
\end{bmatrix}$$
This matrix has 6 free parameters. However, one often states that the polarization is determined by the coherency matrix
$$J=\begin{bmatrix}
E(u_{x}u_{x}^{\ast})&E(u_{x}u_{y}^{\ast})\\
E(u_{y}u_{x}^{\ast})&E(u_{y}u_{y}^{\ast})
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
2E(aa)&E(ac)+E(bd)+i(E(bc)-E(ad))\\
E(ac)+E(bd)-i(E(bc)-E(ad))&2E(cc)
\end{bmatrix}
$$
which has only $4$ free parameters because two pairs of free parameters of $C$ are combined in two free parameters in $J$. So we lost 2 degrees of freedom. Does this mean that $E(ac)=E(bd)$ and $E(bc)=-E(ad)$ or does this mean that the coherency matrix doesn't contain all information on the polarization state?

Answer (score 2):

Jones Matrices cannot express partial polarization.

For that you need Stokes Vectors and the related Mueller Matrices (for transforming one Stokes vector into another).

Interestingly a Stokes Vector can be trivially separated into a fully polarized vector and a fully unpolarized vector.